# How do I restore browser window sizes and locations?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, google-chrome

I have a lot of screen real estate because I have 3 monitors. I was wondering if there was a way to create some sort of bookmark that when I click it this would happen:

- Gmail goes up on my left monitor,
- Google search comes up on my center monitor
- Analytics and iGoogle split across my right monitor.

Right now I have to click each bookmark and then manipulate the Windows which is a little cumbersome.

Is there a solution for this? I am using Windows 7 with Chrome, Firefox, and Internet Explorer 8.

Answer (score 0):

[UltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/) lets you customize application shortcuts to force a given window to open at a specific location and size.  (I'd suspect similar applications like DisplayFusion and Actual Multiple Monitors do this as well, but I can't speak firsthand.)

Comment: What about remembering the exact window size and position on the screen. And the ability to do this all with one click. Kind of like saving your session in firefox but for all windows.

Comment: I don't know of anything offhand that will do it in one click that wouldn't involve some pretty extensive scripting, nothing that will just let you make a "profile" or something.  If you don't mind the coding, AutoHotKey can probably pull it off.